# Jest & React Testing Library:Type of Events dont match

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

im trying some adventures in the testing area, especially i wanted to test some basic react components but i get stuck at the first step. This is a simplified form that i am using in
my application.

The form is working. Im struggling with the test of the view atm.

### What i want:

I would like to test the view without the container and they container with the view.

I wrote some basic test, the way i think they should look like e.g.

- view: test if `change` gets called with the correct data
- presenter: test after `change` gets called what the value of the input is <-this is working, thus not in the code but in the gist

### What i expect to happen:

If i call `fireEvent` in the test, i would like he test to pass.

### What is happening:

The first test is working(obviously), because the component gets initialized with empty values. `onChange` test in the container component is working aswell. The `onChange` test in my view is broken, the types of the events don't match.

How can i test this or achieve the correct type?

### Code:

LoginView.ts (Presenter)

```
import { ChangeEvent, createElement, FunctionComponent } from "react";

export interface LoginViewProps {
    username: string;
    password: string;
    onChange: (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
    onSubmit: () => void;
}

export const LoginView: FunctionComponent<LoginViewProps> = (props: LoginViewProps) => {

    return createElement("div", {},
        createElement("label", {
            htmlFor: "username",
        },
            "Username:",
        ),
        createElement("input", {
            "data-testid": "username",
            type: "text",
            name: "username",
            id: "username",
            value: props.username,
            onChange: props.onChange,
        }),
        createElement("label", {
            htmlFor: "password",
        },
            "Password:",
        ),
        createElement("input", {
            "data-testid": "password",
            type: "password",
            name: "password",
            id: "password",
            value: props.password,
            onChange: props.onChange,
        }),
        createElement("button", {
            type: "button",
            "data-testid": "submit",
            onClick: props.onSubmit,
        },
            "Sign in",
        ),
    );
};

export default LoginView;
```

LoginView.test.ts - Test for the View

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { createElement } from "react";
import { render, fireEvent, cleanup } from "@testing-library/react";
import LoginView, { LoginViewProps } from "./LoginView";

afterEach(cleanup);

describe("Login Presenter", () => {

    /**
     * This works, more coincidence than knowledge
     */
    it("should display div with blank values", async () => {
        const { findByTestId } = renderLoginForm();

        const username = await findByTestId("username");
        const password = await findByTestId("password");

        expect(username).toHaveValue("");
        expect(password).toHaveValue("");
    });

    /**
     * This is not working
     */
    it("should allow entering a username", async () => {
        const onChange = jest.fn();
        const { findByTestId } = renderLoginForm({
            onChange,
        });
        const username = await findByTestId("username");

        fireEvent.change(username, {
            target: {
                id: "username",
                value: "test",
            },
        });

        /**
         * This expect is wrong,
         * received: Object {...}
         * expected: SyntheticBaseEvent {...}
         */
        expect(onChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
            target: {
                id: "username",
                value: "test",
            },
        });
    });

    /**
     * This is not working
     */
    it("should allow entering a password", async () => {
        const onChange = jest.fn();
        const { findByTestId } = renderLoginForm({
            onChange,
        });
        const password = await findByTestId("password");

        fireEvent.change(password, {
            target: {
                id: "password",
                value: "test",
            },
        });

        /**
         * This expect is wrong,
         * received: Object {...}
         * expected: SyntheticBaseEvent {...}
         */
        expect(onChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
            target: {
                id: "password",
                value: "test",
            },
        });
    });

    it("should submit the form with username, password", async () => {
        /**
         * What to write here?
         *
         * How can i test the values that i provided
         */
    });
});


function renderLoginForm(props: Partial<LoginViewProps> = {}) {
    const defaultProps: LoginViewProps = {
        username: "",
        password: "",
        onChange() {
            return;
        },
        onSubmit() {
            return;
        },
    };
    return render(createElement(LoginView, {
        ...defaultProps,
        ...props,
    }));
}
```

### Error:

```
> jest

 FAIL  src/react/LoginForm/LoginView.test.ts
  ● Login Presenter › should allow entering a username

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    - Expected
    + Received

    - Object {
    -   "target": Object {
    -     "id": "username",
    -     "value": "test",
    + SyntheticBaseEvent {
    +   "_reactName": "onChange",
    +   "_targetInst": null,
    +   "bubbles": true,
    +   "cancelable": false,
    +   "currentTarget": null,
    +   "defaultPrevented": false,
    +   "eventPhase": 3,
    +   "isDefaultPrevented": [Function functionThatReturnsFalse],
    +   "isPropagationStopped": [Function functionThatReturnsFalse],
    +   "isTrusted": false,
    +   "nativeEvent": Event {
    +     "isTrusted": false,
        },
    +   "target": <input
    +     data-testid="username"
    +     id="username"
    +     name="username"
    +     type="text"
    +     value=""
    +   />,
    +   "timeStamp": 1640165302072,
    +   "type": "change",
      },

    Number of calls: 1

      31 |              });
      32 |
    > 33 |              expect(onChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
         |                               ^
      34 |                      target: {
      35 |                              id: "username",
      36 |                              value: "test",

      at _callee2$ (src/react/LoginForm/LoginView.test.ts:33:20)
      at tryCatch (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:40)
      at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:294:22)
      at Generator.next (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:119:21)
      at asyncGeneratorStep (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
      at _next (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:25:9)

  ● Login Presenter › should allow entering a password

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    - Expected
    + Received

    - Object {
    -   "target": Object {
    -     "id": "password",
    -     "value": "test",
    + SyntheticBaseEvent {
    +   "_reactName": "onChange",
    +   "_targetInst": null,
    +   "bubbles": true,
    +   "cancelable": false,
    +   "currentTarget": null,
    +   "defaultPrevented": false,
    +   "eventPhase": 3,
    +   "isDefaultPrevented": [Function functionThatReturnsFalse],
    +   "isPropagationStopped": [Function functionThatReturnsFalse],
    +   "isTrusted": false,
    +   "nativeEvent": Event {
    +     "isTrusted": false,
        },
    +   "target": <input
    +     data-testid="password"
    +     id="password"
    +     name="password"
    +     type="password"
    +     value=""
    +   />,
    +   "timeStamp": 1640165302102,
    +   "type": "change",
      },

    Number of calls: 1

      53 |              });
      54 |
    > 55 |              expect(onChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
         |                               ^
      56 |                      target: {
      57 |                              id: "password",
      58 |                              value: "test",

      at _callee3$ (src/react/LoginForm/LoginView.test.ts:55:20)
      at tryCatch (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:40)
      at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:294:22)
      at Generator.next (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:119:21)
      at asyncGeneratorStep (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
      at _next (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:25:9)

 PASS  src/react/LoginForm/Login.test.ts

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests:       2 failed, 6 passed, 8 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.035 s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

### Gist:

https://gist.github.com/simann/9cbf01f28602d59ba988ef608df99bc0

### Final remarks:

Besides the error above, i am still in need for some tests of the `submit` function, if anyone could provide me with some information i would be really grateful.

Any other hints or improvemets are welcome aswell.

#### EDIT

For clarification i will add the code of the container aswell

Login.ts

```
import { ChangeEvent, Component, createElement } from "react";
import LoginForm from "./LoginView";

interface LoginState {
    password: string;
    username: string;
}

export class Login extends Component<null, LoginState> {

    constructor(props: null) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            password: "",
            username: "",
        };

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    onChange(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        const { id, value } = event.target;
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            [id]: value,
        });
    }


    onSubmit() {
        console.log(this.state.username, this.state.password);
        /**
         * Do a websocket request with the values
         */
    }

    render() {
        return createElement(LoginForm, {
            password: this.state.password,
            username: this.state.username,
            onChange: this.onChange,
            onSubmit: this.onSubmit,
        });
    }

}

export default Login;
```

Login.test.ts

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { createElement } from "react";
import { render, fireEvent, cleanup } from "@testing-library/react";
import Login from "./Login";

afterEach(cleanup);

describe("Login Container", () => {
    it("should display a blank login form with blank values", async () => {
        const { findByTestId } = renderLogin();

        const username = await findByTestId("username");
        const password = await findByTestId("password");

        expect(username).toHaveValue("");
        expect(password).toHaveValue("");
    });

    it("should allow entering a username", async () => {
        const { findByTestId } = renderLogin();
        const username = await findByTestId("username");

        fireEvent.change(username, {
            target: {
                id: "username",
                value: "test",
            },
        });

        expect(username).toHaveValue("test");
    });

    it("should allow entering a password", async () => {
        const { findByTestId } = renderLogin();
        const password = await findByTestId("password");

        fireEvent.change(password, {
            target: {
                id: "password",
                value: "test",
            },
        });

        expect(password).toHaveValue("test");
    });

    it("should submit the form with username, password", async () => {
        /**
         * What to write here?
         *
         * How do i test the values that are in my state?
         */
    });
});


function renderLogin() {
    return render(createElement(Login));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The tests are mainly failing because you're comparing two different objects.

The object passed by React to the event handler is an instance of SyntheticEvent which is a wrapper around the browser's native event, and is more complex than the object you're comparing it to.

Despite having a similar interface to the native event, the SyntheticEvent class is an implementation detail of React and you should avoid implementing your tests around its structure, especially for object matching tests.

A better approach is it to wrap your `onChange` prop inside another function which will call it passing only the event value.

```
...
createElement("input", {
    "data-testid": "username",
    type: "text",
    name: "username",
    id: "username",
    value: props.username,
    onChange: (event) => {
        props.onChange(event.target.value);
    },
})
...
```

Then, on your test you can write:

```
...
fireEvent.change(password, {
    target: {
        value: "test",
    },
});

expect(onChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith("test");
...
```

To test submitted values, use React `useState` to save the values of your input fields.

```
...
const [username, setUsername] = React.useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");
...
createElement("input", {
    "data-testid": "username",
    type: "text",
    name: "username",
    id: "username",
    value: props.username,
    onChange: (event) => {
        setUsername(event.target.value);
        props.onChange(event.target.value);
    },
}),
createElement("input", {
    "data-testid": "password",
    type: "password",
    name: "password",
    id: "password",
    value: props.password,
    onChange: () => {
        setPassword(event.target.value);
        props.onChange(event.target.value);
    },
}),
createElement("button", {
    type: "button",
    "data-testid": "submit",
    onClick: () => {
        props.onSubmit(username, password)
    },
},
    "Sign in",
)
```

Then in your test you ca

```
it("should submit the form with username, password", async () => {
    const onSubmit = jest.fn();
    const { findByTestId } = renderLoginForm({
        onSubmit,
    });

    const username = await findByTestId("username");
    const password = await findByTestId("password");
    const submit = await findByTestId("submit");

    fireEvent.change(username, { target: { value: "username" } });
    fireEvent.change(password, { target: { value: "password" } });
    fireEvent.click(submit);

    expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledWith("username", "password");
});
```

Aside from that, you should use JSX to create components instead of `createElement`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got that part with the onChange function. The part i dont get is about `const [username, setUsername] = React.useState("");`.  I would introduce a second variable for the same data and use that in the login function. That would make the variables in the container obsolete?

Comment: the other way is to use `refs` to keep a reference to the input field and you access its value inside the submit handler.

Answer (score 0):

By your current component code and test in

```
expect(onChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
  target: {
    id: "username",
    value: "test",
  },
});
```

You actually want to check "there is object that contains `target: { id: "username", value: "test" }` while currently you check "it's exactly that object". Here [`expect.objectContaining`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectobjectcontainingobject) helps:

```
expect(onChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  expect.objectContaining({
    target: {
      id: "username",
      value: "test",
    },
  })
);
```